# Out of Memory "Set CS6 = New LabelManager2.Application" (VB6 - Codesoft)

Tags: oop, com, vb6

I build VB6 Application to printing label using Codesoft 9 Application, but when I try to execute the code, the error appears "Out Of Memory" and then it debug to this code :

```
Set CS6 = New LabelManager2.Application
```

So, what's wrong with my code, any idea???

The error should be an exception with this message:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
{3624B9C0-9E5D-11D3-A896-00C04F324E22} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following
error: 8007000e Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY)).
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with the CodeSoft9 application - have you asked them?

Comment: Do you have enough free memory on the system where you try to run this? A simple allocation of an object usually doesn't fail with OoM, unless the COM object is buggy or you're really OoM.

Comment: please post some more code ... do you use this line inside a loop, or in a procedure which is called inside a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue probably involves licensing.
Only the **Enterprise** version of *Teklynx Codesoft 9* and *10* support the full ActiveX *LabelManager2.dll* (`Lppx2.Application`) component. I can duplicate your problem using the Pro level or not starting the *Codesoft* application with the Enterprise Evaluation license first.

I think that the .Net wrapper version *Lppnet.dll*  (`Tkx.Lppa.Application`), may work with the Pro level license, but it is very limited version.

Here is some additional information:

- If you are running in Demo/Evaluation mode you can set the license level of the demo in the program's options
- To open options with *Codesoft 9*, click  `Tools`\ `Options`
- To open configuration with *Codesoft 10*, click `Tools`\ `Configuration`
- On the left side of the resulting dialog, there is a set of icons. Scroll to the bottom and click `Product Mode`
- Select `Codesoft Enterprise RFID`
- Click `OK`
- Close and restart the program

When running in a demo mode you have to start the *Codesoft* application first before running your program. It may not load on its own unless you have an Enterprise license installed. I don’t currently have a non-demo *Codesoft* license to do testing on this aspect.

I also do not have *Codesoft 2012* or *2014* installed so I don’t know if everything listed applies directly to those versions. They have made major changes to the way licensing works and installing them uninstalls the older version.